# Using binary JSON formats with d3 xhr

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, bson

So,

I'm doing some D3 work on source data ~3GB. I figure it's maybe reasonable to load 1-10 mb in a single call before people are going to be annoyed with load times, so I'm looking at a factor of 1000 compression on my dataset before I can throw it in browser. Most of this is accomplished with various aggregations, but the less information I have to throw away, the richer the interaction, so I've been looking at binary JSON formats to maybe get a factor of 2 or so for free (maybe more if because I think I can replace some long hashes with some short integers).

Anyways, actual question. Do D3 xhr requests work with BSON, UBJSON, or smile? It seems like none of the 3 have come far enough to have an official associated MIME type (there's some recommendations but I didn't see them on the official list). Also, considering they're based off of **JSON**, there seems to be little mention of Javascript in the (BSON, UBJSON, smile) parsing libraries (is that because Javascript can read them natively, or no one has found it worthwhile to implement...)

Comment: `d3.xhr` is a generic method, so you should be able to load your data with it.